# How to make a confusion matrix plot with percentage values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot a 2x2 confusion matrix in Matlab in such a way that the plot would have percentage values in each of the grid boxes in this way:

[image]

In summary I'm asking for how to make a plot like the one above when you're given the percentage values in a matrix:

> V = [0.15, 0.30; 0.05, 0.50]

Is it possible to make a plot like that in Matlab? I did think of drawing the vertical lines and then plotting some text into spesific coordinates, but is this the only way to do this?

Comment: So you want to draw four boxes and write some text in it? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I wondered do I have to draw the vertical lines one by one and the plot text to some coordinates...or is there an easier way? I could of course do this by hand, but my problem is that I need a script because I need to make more than 100 of these pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you how you could do it. I did it just for fun!

You can change the size of your input matrix as you wish.

```
A=[0.3 0.2 ; 0.1 0.7];

sA=size(A);
Aplot=rot90(A,3);
figure;hold on


rectangle('Position',[0,0,sA(2),sA(1)],'Facecolor',[1 1 1],'edgecolor','none')

for ii=0:sA(1)
    plot([0 sA(2)], [ii ii],'k','Linewidth',3)
end
for ii=0:sA(2)
    plot([ii ii],[0 sA(1)],'k','Linewidth',3)
end
for ii=1:sA(2)
    for jj=1:sA(1)
    text((ii-1)+0.35,(jj-1)+0.5,strcat(num2str(Aplot(ii,jj)*100),' %'),'fontsize',30)
    end
end


margin=0.05;
axis([0-margin sA(2)+margin 0-margin sA(1)+margin])
axis off
```

[image]

With Matlab 2014b and the new graphic engine, smoother option:

[image]

Comment: @jjepsuomi you can probably play a lot more with this, like using LaTeX interpreter and so on

Comment: Which version did you use? Just wondering if the text would look nicer with the new graphics engine...

Comment: I did this with the oldone @kkuilla, but let me use the new and add an image.

Comment: @kkuilla Also the corners of the lines!